# How to delete end of a string in python

Tags: python

I have a string looks like this

```
urse/project/kb/use.js
```

from this string i need to get

```
urse/project/kb/
```

`use.js` the name will always change except `.js`.

Or delete the string till the first `/` from the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has a dedicated module for dealing with file paths:

```
In [13]: os.path.dirname('urse/project/kb/use.js')
Out[13]: 'urse/project/kb'
```

Append a trailing [`os.sep`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep) as required (or, better yet, stick to using the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module for manipulating paths).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = 'urse/project/kb/use.js'
>>> s[:s.rfind('/') + 1]
'urse/project/kb/'
```

Comment: In this case I would prefer os.path, but if we are going to split other strings than paths, I think that `s.rpartition('/')[0]` looks more "obvious" / "pythonic" than first finding the index and then slice it.